# wordpress multisite config issue needs help

Tags: multisite

Here is the `wp-config.php` code:

```
test/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain name .com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

The main site is served from **public_html/wordpress**
so when someone visits **abc.com** they are redirected to **abc.com/wordpress**

I have another site which is **abc.com/wordpress/cde**.
The issue is when I post under this sub-domain (for multisite) the post is automatically posted to site 1.

Also, I am not able to change permalinks for second site. When ever I hit update it redirects me to site and updates site 1's permalinks.

UPDATE 1: the permalinks for second site as as follows 
abc.com/wordpress/

rather it should be abc.com/wordpress/cde

That's the issue I am trying to figure out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);` to `define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);` to start with. Maybe you need to modify you .htaccess file as well.

For more info the WordPress codex has a lot of info:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

Comment: Thanks @tombaro, I actually already have get that working